# My first question — Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

I have the following issue: I want to execute a script where I'm trying to insert data from a database that I restored (iNode-8-24-14-Orig) into a database that I created.

The code is:

```
/****************************************************/
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[XHQ_HIER_DEF] ON;
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[XHQ_HIER_DEF]
           ([HIER_KEY]
           ,[HIER_NAME]
           ,[HIER_DESC]
           ,[SYNONYM_DEF_LEVEL]
           ,[CRT_XHQUSERID]
           ,[CRT_TIMESTAMP]
           ,[CRT_TZ_BIAS]
           ,[UPDT_XHQUSERID]
           ,[UPDT_TIMESTAMP]
           ,[UPDT_TZ_BIAS])
SELECT [HIER_KEY]
      ,[HIER_NAME]
      ,[HIER_DESC]
      ,[SYNONYM_DEF_LEVEL]
      ,[CRT_XHQUSERID]
      ,[CRT_TIMESTAMP]
      ,[CRT_TZ_BIAS]
      ,[UPDT_XHQUSERID]
      ,[UPDT_TIMESTAMP]
      ,[UPDT_TZ_BIAS]
  FROM [iNode-8-24-14-Orig].[dbo].[XHQ_HIER_DEF]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[XHQ_HIER_DEF] OFF;
GO
/****************************************************/
```

But I get this error for each table:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'XPKXHQ_HIER_DEF'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.XHQ_HIER_DEF'. The duplicate key value is
>   (1).

Any idea how can I fix this? I want to mention that I have the same tables and columns in both databases. I know is saying that I'm already using the same primary key, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Perhaps SQL Server?)

Comment: is `[dbo].[XHQ_HIER_DEF]` empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is my first question on this site.

And we care... why?

> Any idea how can i fix this?

Read the error, fix the data? The error says very clear what the issue is:

> Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.XHQ_HIER_DEF'.

Do not insert the same key value multiple times. Period. If you define a field as primary key, values have per definition to be unique in the key.

There already is an entry with identity 1, or your source data has multiple rows with the same value, which is not valid per your data model.

Generally for problems like this, actually reading the error helps. In your case it is EXTREMELY clear in the description what the issue is, even giving you the value causing the problem:

> The duplicate key value is (1).

Comment: i solved it. I mean..now I have the data in my tables, but it doesn't appear on my GUI. I'll try to fix this problem too. If not, be ready for the second one!!  just kidding
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solution is obvious: do not insert duplicate primary key values.

From your I suppose:

1. You're using MSSQL with linked server
2. PK consists of `HIER_KEY` field only

So:

```
/****************************************************/
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[XHQ_HIER_DEF] ON;
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[XHQ_HIER_DEF]
        ([HIER_KEY]
        ,[HIER_NAME]
        ,[HIER_DESC]
        ,[SYNONYM_DEF_LEVEL]
        ,[CRT_XHQUSERID]
        ,[CRT_TIMESTAMP]
        ,[CRT_TZ_BIAS]
        ,[UPDT_XHQUSERID]
        ,[UPDT_TIMESTAMP]
        ,[UPDT_TZ_BIAS])
SELECT [HIER_KEY]
    ,[HIER_NAME]
    ,[HIER_DESC]
    ,[SYNONYM_DEF_LEVEL]
    ,[CRT_XHQUSERID]
    ,[CRT_TIMESTAMP]
    ,[CRT_TZ_BIAS]
    ,[UPDT_XHQUSERID]
    ,[UPDT_TIMESTAMP]
    ,[UPDT_TZ_BIAS]
FROM [iNode-8-24-14-Orig].[dbo].[XHQ_HIER_DEF] T1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[XHQ_HIER_DEF] T2 
        WHERE 
        T1.HIER_KEY = T2.HIER_KEY
)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[XHQ_HIER_DEF] OFF;
GO
/****************************************************/
```

Warning: performance of such insert could be **especially** terrible.